Another me keeps warning me in my head!

Another me keeps warning me in my head! (source)

(It seems that the writer is a Japanese translator who lives in the US.)
Is Another me correct even though me is an objective case pronoun? I guess that the translator used Another me because "Another I" sounds odd in English. I wonder if Another me can be replaced with "Another self" or "Another ego".

Yes, "another me" is perfectly idiomatic.  Another "self" might work, but "another me" already has a well-established usage for this sort of thing.  Compare:  "evil me": "I didn't eat the last cookie. It could have been evil me."  And "baby me".  "That's a picture of baby me."  i.e. me as a baby.  And "lonesome me". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc-2eO8FJzk

Thank you, TimR. Is it OK to use "another me" in formal writing?

Formal writing might avoid the use of the first person, in favour of third person.

"Another me" is not less acceptable than "another self...in my head"   :-)

You wouldn't use "in my head" in a formal article.  Speaking of something happening in the "head" is an informal way of speaking of the psyche.

Grammar (of English, Japanese, or any other language) is used mostly in real situations.  In strange and unreal situations things don't work well.
For example, "I" or "me" is normally one person, and one personality.  The idea that there are two different entities that are both "me", and which may communicate, is a strange one. It may indicate a disordered mental state or it may be a metaphor for something.
And English grammar can't deal with this very well. The sentence that you quote as correct as possible, given the odd idea that is being expressed.


Is "Another me" correct even though me is an objective case pronoun?

I have my own theory about this.
Comparing English grammar to other languages (Spanish, German, etc), you expect the rules to be:
"I" - nominative case
"me" - accusative, dative case (As a direct or indirect object).
Historically, going back a thousand years, that was accurate.  Then English crystallized or solidified into a very order-dependent language, Subject-Verb-Object, and lost track of the word endings. You no longer  have the many inflections of words found in the past, or in closely related languages.
So, the situation exists where the ordering of the words determines their role.
This proceeds to be the case for hundreds of years.
Now, in modern times, when native speakers think about "I" and "me", another rule comes to mind, out of the blue, of it's own accord.

When appearing at the very beginning of a sentence, use "I".
Every place else in the sentence, use "me".

That's why we'd say "It was me!" instead of "It was I!". Because it's following the new rule about order. And so it is here in your question about "another me".  If common general usage determines correctness, the new rule has become "correct".
